# Broken memory card cover Canon 7D markII, is there an override?

Tags: canon, memory-card, canon-7d

The memory card cover on my Canon 7D markII has broken off. I am unable to replace it at the moment but need to use my camera.

Is there a way to override the automatic off setting for when the card cover is open?

Comment: If it's just the actual door that's broken, you can get a replacement (probably salvaged from a "parts" camera) on eBay for about $35-40. You don't even need a screwdriver to swap them out.

Comment: Many thanks Michael (I'm based in South Africa so a bit tougher to find parts)

Answer (score 2):

The memory card door has a tab that engages a very small micro-switch on the camera body when closed. If you can find a way to activate this switch, your camera will operate without the door closed or even if it is missing.

Be careful not to damage the delicate micro-switch.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Mike